# cohen kappa score in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

According to scikit learn documentation, the cohen kappa score can be calculated as this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
y_true = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
y_pred = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(cohen_kappa_score(y_true, y_pred)
1
```

where the 0 and 1  are the labels assigned by annotators.

however, if both annotators never assign the second label(e.g. 0) then the score is nan ! which should be 1 (if i am not mistaken) since both annotators agreed.

```
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
y_true = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
y_pred = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(cohen_kappa_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

```
packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:604: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  k = np.sum(w_mat * confusion) / np.sum(w_mat * expected)
nan
```

What am i missing?

Update:
I found this in the github issues: 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9624

Still did not get it that this is a perfect agreement at random, where it should be considered as correct annotation

Answer (score 2):

Cohen's Kappa consider agreement without chance; when labels of both annotators are labeled with just one class, its random agreement is 1 which results in division by zero.
if we consider the following simple example:

```
from metrics import cohen_kappa_score
cohen_kappa_score([0,0],[0,0])
```

here the confusion matrix equals to :

```
conf = [2]
```

which means that for class 0, there is two cases of agreement between both annotator 1 & annotator 2.

```
p{o} = 2/2=1
p{e} = p{0} = 2/2 = 1
K=p{o}-p{e}/1-p{e} = 1-1/ 1-1 = nan
```

in the last equation as our final Kappa value, there is division by zero.